# How to serialize empty pandas dataframe into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, serialization

I have a dataframe output and I would like to be able to serialize it as a list of dictionaries and convert the date timestamps to string. I know i can do `to_json(orient='records', data_format='iso)`  but it is getting converted to a string and `json.loads(to_json_df)` throws

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I have also tried to_dict but it does not convert timestamps.

What is the best way to be able to do that? Here is the rest `GET` call in flask:

```
columns = ['project_number', 'people_manager', 'quality_manager', 'inserted_at']
projects = get_projects_info(project_ids) # returns pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
serialized_projects = projects.to_dict('records')
projects = [
   {
     'projectNumber': project['project_number'],
     'peopleManager': project['people_manager'],
     'qualityManager': project['quality_manager'],
     'insertedAt': project['inserted_at'],
   } for project in serialized_projects
]

return {
  'projects': projects
}, 200
```

Expected Output:

```
{
'projects': [
   {
     'projectNumber': 123,
     'peopleManager': '',
     'qualityManager': '',
     'insertedAt': '2019/2/23'
   },
   {
     'projectNumber': 124,
     'peopleManager': '',
     'qualityManager': '',
     'insertedAt': '2019/2/23'
   },
]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `serialized_projects = projects.to_json()` get you what you need?

Comment: It does not it adds weird characters and makes it a string.

Comment: Can you show what weird characters are added? It's not really clear what your expected outcome is? Question title says json, but your `projects` variable in the example ends up as a dict within a list. Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: @ChrisA updated the question. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a no brainer

```
import json
columns = ['project_number', 'people_manager', 'quality_manager', 'inserted_at']
projects = get_projects_info(project_ids) # returns pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
serialized_projects = projects.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
serialized_projects = json.loads(serialized_projects)

projects = [
   {
     'projectNumber': project['project_number'],
     'peopleManager': project['people_manager'],
     'qualityManager': project['quality_manager'],
     'insertedAt': project['inserted_at'],
   } for project in serialized_projects
]

return {
  'projects': projects
}, 200
```